# Can one use the iPhone X's (and newer models) infrared camera for photographic purposes?

Tags: iphone, infrared, apps

Apple's smartphone iPhone X has an infrared camera embedded inside the top of the device:

[image]

Can this infrared camera be used for photographic purposes, or it is just used for FaceID?
(I am also curious to know whether or not developers have access to the camera's data.)

Comment: File a bug with Apple.  Tell them why you want to use it.  Ask them to make it available through their camera APIs.  Wait and see.

Comment: If you can get access to the api, you might be disappointed when you find out the resulting image is only about 1.4megapixels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the (currently only) answer at the recent StackOverflow question, [Is it possible to access the infrared camera on iPhone X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47190065/1123413),

> not via the approved iOS API library calls. But undocumented API should be possible if you guess how to do it.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I had searched in vain for this topic! More on this later as things develop, I guess...